# Best practice for using modules with their own/common dependencies

Tags: javascript, browserify, commonjs

The setup:

main.js

```
var model = require("./model");

var someLibrary = require("someLibrary");
```

model.js

```
var someLibrary = require("someLibrary");

module.exports = function(){
    //blah
}
```

Question:

(1) Does my Browserify bundle have two entries for the common library? If so, do I use something like factor-bundle on npm to reduce the size of my bundle?

(2) Is there a central place where I should list all of the nested dependencies of my own modules?

(3) If I find myself requiring mostly the same scripts in each module, should I consider refactoring? Is that a code smell?

,Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can put the node_modules directory in `~/`.  That is basically your home directory.  As for browserify the files should be cached.